# TcpClient.GetStream() returns null

Tags: c#, tcpclient, data-stream

I have a TcpPeer class that represents the TCP side when converting from another data transfer method (this is what the IPeer interface is for). But for unknown to me reason TcpClient.GetStream() in the constructor returns null, which is why other methods and the whole program don't work

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
class TcpPeer : IPeer
{
    private TcpClient _client;
    private NetworkStream _stream;
    public TcpPeer(string ip, int port)
    {
        _client = new TcpClient(ip, port);
        _stream = _client.GetStream();
    }
    public byte[] Read()
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[8192];
        
        //exception here
        int len = _stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

        Array.Resize(ref data, len);
        return data;
    }
    public void Write(byte[] msg)
    {
        //and here
        _stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
    }
}

interface IPeer
{
    byte[] Read();
    void Write(byte[] data);
}
```

Comment: You probably aren't making a connection to server.  The server may not be runnning or you may not have a route to the server.  I usually start by verifying the route using PING from cmd.exe  >PING IP

Comment: *"You must call the Connect method first, or the GetStream method will throw an InvalidOperationException."* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream?view=net-6.0#remarks

Comment: Side point: `TcpClient` must be disposed, you are not doing that for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to validate that your tcp connection was successful (Unfortunately, Microsoft does not mention this in their [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?view=net-6.0)). Eg:

```cs
public TcpPeer(string ip, int port)
{
    try {
        _client = new TcpClient(ip, port);
        if (_client.Connected)
            _stream = _client.GetStream();
        //else
            // handle error / dispose
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle error / dispose
    }
}
```